# Use robots.txt to prevent privacy policy, terms and conditions, and guarantees from being crawled and indexed by Google

Tags: html, php, robots.txt, url-encoding, meta-robots

I need to block pages such as privacy policy, terms and conditions, and guarantees from being crawled and indexed by Google.  They might be unoriginal.  I use them for my multiple websites and they have no content relevant to be ranked by search engines.

Their links are like `https://example.com/privacy.php`

I don't want to mess up and end up being penalized by Google

Comment: What is this "different way" you refer to in the question title? What you describe in the question would seem to be exactly what `robots.txt` is used for, in a _normal way_. So, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @OskarSkog i don't understand what i should do..please give me a step by step on how to do it

Comment: @w3dk I just need a step by step way of creating the txt file ...if you can send me the sample id appreciate...i don't know the best way to do it,either robots.txt or noindex- i simply don't know

Comment: Google understands that pages like these are often similar or the across many sites.   It won't cause any issues to allow them to be crawled.   Google generally only ranks them for queries like "mysite privacy policy".  Google may use the existence of contact forms and privacy policies as a ranking signal, so it is a good idea to let Google crawl them.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to your C panel>>public_html>>site directory and create a file named **"robots.txt"** in it paste the following code

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /privacy.php/
Disallow: /terms.php/
Allow:
Sitemap: http://www.xxxxxxx.xxx/sitemap.xml
```

Change the links above to match up with your site.
With the above, **google bots can never crawl** any information in the **"Disallow"** field.

Comment: 1. I think the trailing slashes after the PHP files is erroneous. 2. Google *can* crawl that information if it chooses to, they just choose not to do so. So saying "never" isn't quite accurate.

Comment: @Yesokay that's great. I appreciate. Do you agree with "I think the trailing slashes after the PHP files is erroneous"

Comment: @Nina , just remove the slash, the rest will work out fine

Comment: @Yesokay "The home page for this site is disallowed by robots.txt, please allow it" How can i do this yet I have not disallowed my homepage, what might be wrong ?

Comment: @Nina,  can you copy and paste what's in your robots.txt file and a link to the site?